# AS3 panning very slow in only one direction and only with Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air

[image]
I have a couple dozen collision detections going on each frame as well as a couple dozen objects panning as the character moves left or right (but only if near the edge of the screen).  It actually works perfectly when publish in FlashPlayer21 but if I use Adobe AIR, it goes super slow.  This only happens when the  character is going right and the background is moving left (so the "camera is panning right").  When the character goes left, it is super smooth.  I'm using nearly identical code for both with the exception of a different sign (+/-) here or there.  Maybe I shouldn't worry about this, or maybe I need to test on my iphone or a tablet but since I don't know how to do that yet... isn't that the whole point of Adobe having these AIR for desktop and internal iOS mobile device simulators?

Here's the relevant code:

```
    private function panScreen2(c:Runner,speedFac:Number,...depthSets):void{
        if (c == char){ // if the c:Runner object is the character in play
             // I use drivers to cause objects that can only be displayed on every 8th pixel to still recieve floating point number values for animation
            var cDepth: int = c._drives.parent.parent.getChildIndex(c._drives.parent);
            // "camera" pans to left as character goes left
            if (c.x <= 500 && c._drives._facingRight == false && c._speed !=0)
            {
                for (var i:int = depthSets.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
                    for (var j:int = depthSets[i].arr.length-1; j >= 0; j--){
                        var depthDif:int = -cDepth+depthSets[i].arr[j].parent.parent.getChildIndex(depthSets[i].arr[j].parent)
                        depthSets[i].arr[j].x -= (c._speed)*depthDif*depthSets[i].ratio-speedFac;
                    }
                }
            // "camera" pans to right as character goes right sending objects to left
            } else if (c.x >= 1000 && c._drives._facingRight == true && c._speed !=0)
            {
                for (var i:int = depthSets.length-1; i >= 0; i--){ 
                    for (var j:int = depthSets[i].arr.length-1; j >= 0; j--){
                        var depthDif:int = -cDepth+depthSets[i].arr[j].parent.parent.getChildIndex(depthSets[i].arr[j].parent)
                        depthSets[i].arr[j].x -= (c._speed)*depthDif*depthSets[i].ratio+speedFac;
                    }
                }
            } else
            {
                c.x += c._speed;                
            }
        }
    }
```

and then I call the function like so:

```
panScreen(c,{arr:allBlocks,ratio:1},{arr:allDepth,ratio:1},{arr:allBears,ratio:1});
```

depthSets are the extra parameters I pass when calling the function.  It is an object which consists of an array and a ratio.  This function iterates through the array (actually Vector, if that matters) and moves everything to the right or left by an amount determined by the ratio and the speed of the character.  Pretty straight forward, and again, it works like a charm in Flash Player 21 and works smooth as butter when the character goes leftward which sends all the objects to the right as a "camera" pan.  So what's going on with trying to go to the right?

Comment: If you load up your stage with nothing at x < 500, do you still get the choppy animation?  Also, is there anything you haven't shown that creates new objects as you pan right?  Also, what's the purpose of the `getChildIndex()` calls to calculate `depthDif`?  That looks like a potentially-expensive call.

Comment: Nothing is created as panning right happens. Yes I still get slow animation when nothing is at <500 (I'll try to double check that at lunch). The depthDif is used for motion parallax (objects that have a higher order pan more). I'll try removing that and see what happens as well.